# Are there any valid reasons for disallowing characters and limiting the length of passwords?

Tags: security, passwords

I've come across quite a few sites that either limit the length they allow passwords to be and/or disallow certain characters. That's limiting to me as I want to widen and lengthen the search space of my password. It also gives me an uncomfortable sense that they might not be hashing.

Are there *good* reasons for either setting an upper length or excluding characters in passwords?

Comment: Sure! It makes it easier to brute-force-guess people's passwords! :P

Comment: Are we talking valid "Technical" reasons or valid "Business" reasons?

Comment: @Martin: I was thinking technical but either I suppose.

Comment: Not that anyone would likely do so, but I wouldn't want to store passwords longer than say a thousand characters, for database performance and storage reasons (as minimal as it might be). Limiting a password to 8 characters or so just defies wisdom!

Comment: @JYelton Why do you care what the original password length is? The hash will always be the same size. I certainly hope you're not storing them in plaintext...

Comment: @Pewpewarrows: I never store in plain text, but I (incorrectly) assumed the hashes would vary in size as well.

Comment: See [Why do some websites and programs restrict password characteristics?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/1534/414) and [What chars should I not allow in passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/2096/414), over at [security.se].

Comment: It allows people to determine that the host is a complete idiot who is probably storing the passwords in plain text in an access database!

Comment: @Martin Beckett: You mean that is the reason Skype only allows you a 20 character password? That would be sort of scary...

Comment: "*That's limiting to me as I want to widen and lengthen the search space of my password*" - 16 choices is 0x0 to 0xF and 0b0000 to 0b1111. Same size search space. It's only limiting if they restrict both characters AND length, otherwise you can tradeoff less of one for more of the other and keep the same search space.

Answer (score 27):

## No

There are no *good* reasons.

EDIT:
I cannot prove that there are no good reasons, because one cannot prove a negative. I can think of no good reasons for this - as others pointed out, the hash will be the same size regardless of the size of the input, and eliminating valid characters (from the question context) just reduces the state-space. The answer seems obvious on its face: there are no *good* reasons. There may be a large number of reasons that sound good or that seem good, but they aren't. If they were, someone would have posted them here already, or if not here then certainly on security.stackexchange.com, and this answer would not have been so heavily upvoted.

Comment: This.  The only reason is because someone **thinks** it will increase security, when it usually just **decreases** security.

Comment: I agree, but the comment Kissaki makes about encoding is valid. Some stacks/programmers just can't seem to get the encoding correct, for them limiting to ASCII is a cheap hack to make it work.

Comment: Could you at least try to elaborate?  Either you don't know this for a fact, or you have reason to believe that common/existing reasons aren't valid.  Giving you the benefit of the doubt and assuming the latter, you should be explaining *why* those reasons are not valid.

Comment: -1 - I can think of several good reasons for limiting passwords to a given character set. Likewise, having to support touch-tone phone passwords as well as ones you type via a keyboard is also a situation you have to keep in mind.

Comment: -1. No justification, just opinion. If you're going to make a blanket statement, back it up.

Comment: This is now being discussed on our [meta-discussion site](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1816/is-this-really-the-sort-of-answer-we-want-on-our-site): it would be helpful to understand why a single-word answer is so popular and what we can do to improve the quality of answers like this.

Comment: @Mark: Obvious answer given the context of the question, but I will elaborate in the edits. Frankly surprised at the upvotes.

Comment: @Rob Z: really? odd that you didn't bother to list any of them in the answers...

Comment: @Michael: one cannot prove a negative

Comment: @Steve - A comment isn't a place to post an answer and I up-voted the answers that have good reasons. If I manage to find an article I'm looking for I'll also be posting an answer.

Comment: @Rob Z: fair enough, will check back later.

Comment: @Steven A. Lowe. In general [You can prove a negative](http://departments.bloomu.edu/philosophy/pages/content/hales/articlepdf/proveanegative.pdf) And if fact IMHO I think you have. 1. If good reasons exist they would be posted. 2. They haven't been posted. 3. Therefore good reasons don't exist.

Comment: @Conrad Frix: That is difficult to wrap my head around. There is always a point where (2) is true, and therefore (3) is true. It doesn't make sense that a change in the condition of (2) could alter the state of (3). If a good reason exists, then it *always* existed, regardless of when that reason was brought to light. If we were to find unicorn fossils, we wouldn't say that they *now* exist after having not existed previously. They would have always existed.

Comment: @Corey you're right we wouldn't say that they *now* exist, we would say we *now know* they exist. This actually did happen with Black Swans. You should note that positive proofs have this same problem namely that if the state of a premise changes then the proof changes. e.g. (1) If it summer its warm outside (2) Its summer (3) its warm outside. Obviously (3) is only true for 1/4 of the year. In the end the only point I was trying to make is that you can prove a negative with the same degree of validity as you can prove anything else.

Comment: Per the OWASP guide there can be good reasons to limit length. In short, some good algorithms for storing passwords such as bcrypt have a limit: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html#maximum-password-lengths in that case there is a good reason :)

Answer (score 27):

Limiting the length can be a measure to limit the execution time of the hashing as well as limiting bandwidth (and both of those are *really* marginal anyway). Other than that, there is no good reason, especially from a security point of view.

One could say: “People will forget longer passwords more easily” – but that’s really a stupid statement and doesn’t get to the point at all.

As for characters, as long as you are aware of potential encoding issues with data transfer and/or migration in the future (e.g. you will switch from ASCII to UTF-8 in 2 years) allowing more characters can only be good for passwords strengths.

Comment: Given the overhead of any modern protocol length can absolutely not be a good reason -- other than a high limit like 1K just to prevent certain attacks/nonsense.

Comment: Limiting the execution time of hashing is generally bad. The longer it takes to calculate a hash, the longer it takes to brute-force it.

Comment: Although that’s right it’s always a trade-off. You don’t want to always calculate the best hash which takes the longest. Hence asymmetric handshake vs symmetric data stream in VPN etc.

Answer (score 21):

**Yes**, there is a reason for special characters.

Disallowing special characters is more of a usability thing, rather than security related. First of all they might get mangled by encoding problems. Second, even if you'd guarantee to always use same encoding, there is still the problem of input device. You'd be depending on having full keyboard (which eliminates most mobile devices), with same keyboard layout. Later differ not only between languages, but also between OSs, layouts for Windows, Linux and OSX may be a bit different. So I see good reason not to allow password like: `√Ω≈ç∫∞§…¬å∑±`.

Comment: unless you are *providing* a password to your users, that is, if they are the ones entering the password themselves then if they so choose to use some strange math symbol is really their business.  now i do agree with the encoding issue here though find it more of an excuse to pass below the radar incompetence than a actual good reason to prevent certain characters arbitrarily.

Comment: @new: it's not their business. If they shoot themselves in the foot, they will still perceive as problem with your application and call your support.

Comment: @Newtopian: I hate it when I, as a user, get circumscribed by reason of ignorance (such as not be able to specify a ["+"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333461/regular-expression-which-matches-a-pattern-or-is-an-empty-string) in my email address). Sometimes, however, it's a good idea not to give the users to much rope with which to hang themselves. I think this is such an occasion. It's not about "arbitrarily" preventing certain characters.

Comment: So you're advocating Greeks, Arabs, Chinese and others all use US-ASCII?

Comment: @l0: no, I'm advocating that they use normal, commonly used characters in their languages, rather than some special characters, which may be absent in some layouts.

Comment: I would be inclined to limit the character set to what you can reasonably enter on a phone.

Answer (score 15):

There was a bit of a controversy in the security world a few years back when Chase customers discovered that their passwords were case-insensitive.  It turned out their webpage was just a frontend to some 30-year-old OS/400 backend system, which had a technical limitation that it ignored case.  Fixing this would apparently cost millions of dollars.

The point is, there may be expensive legacy reasons for not allowing passwords over a certain length.
*(Note that I'm not condoning this excuse...)*

Comment: insofar this is the only *good* reason to limit password in any way...  only if the underlying system will hold such limitations in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

Most banks, IT departments, etc. Who enforce maximum password restrictions don't do so for technical reasons. They are perfectly aware of how password hashing works, and how to store complex passwords. They impose these limitations because it reduces the number of calls to support for people who have forgotten their passwords. Is this a good reason to impose that kind of limitation? By no means. But, nevertheless, it is the main reason.

Comment: I see reducing support calls as a `valid Business reason` (Personally I don't actually believe that there is a correlation)

Comment: Well, there are other ways of going about resetting passwords, or educating users on how to choose sufficiently complex passwords that are easy to remember. My last few passwords at work have been > 25 characters, and I've had no trouble remembering them. Also, presumably, people who have trouble remembering their long passwords will still pick shorter passwords, though I have no clue how often that's actually true. Reducing support calls does seem like a valid business reason on the surface, but it's still a lousy reason to restrict password length.

Comment: I think my (and many people) would find accurately typing (not just remembering) 25 characters without seeing the output almost impossible. I have so far fixed 5 typos while typing this!

Comment: Well, remembering isn't the same as typing. Remembering long passwords is very easy if you know how to choose them; simply pick lines from stories or plays, or parts of poems or song lyrics. As long as you change one or two things in there (intentional misspellings, change one word to another that sounds like it or means the same thing, etc), it's quite easy and extremely secure. True, typing it may be harder, but it's no excuse for banks to force you to type less than 8/10/12 characters.

Comment: try typing that 25-letters password on a mobile device

Comment: @Lie: I do, all the time. I generally choose my passwords in a way that they're relatively easy to type. Anyway, that might be a good reason for you not to use such a long password, but it's not a good reason to enforce passwords being under a certain number of characters.

Comment: I just found out that HMRC (UK tax office) not only doesn't accept passwords suggested by Apple's Safari browser, they also didn't accept an existing password anymore because it didn't follow their rules.

Answer (score 8):

> *Are there good reasons for either setting an upper length or excluding characters in passwords?*

I'm going to make a guess and say that some of these restrictions are due to character filtering on their website (`& < > #`) to keep hackers out. While others are the bone-headed ideas that come out of committees of pointy haired bosses.

I've come across a number of really stupid (in my opinion) "security" decisions. As an example, one large investment company handles my IRA accounts as well as my pension. In order to do *any* contact with the pension requires me to type in my password on the telephone (you cannot reach them otherwise). My brokerage/IRA account uses letters (upper and lower case) as well as some punctuation - none of these characters appear on a telephone number pad. If you can't log in with the password over the phone, it lets you reset your brokerage account's password to something you can type in over the phone.

My payroll system (for the consulting company I work for) requires numbers, and only numbers - this lets them use the same database whether the user calls in (I've never done this) or uses the web interface (I only use this).

That being said, it is time to change my password at the office. They have such crazy restrictions that I estimate it will take about half a day to find a password acceptable to the system: at least 2 upper case letters, at least 2 lower case letters, at least 2 digits (which cannot be +/- 1 from the previous password's), at least 2 non-alpha/non-numeric characters, cannot match any of the last 24 passwords, cannot contain any string (forwards or backwards) that is a word (3 or more letters long) in English (also a couple other languages I don't have clearance to know). I *think* the minimum length is like 10-11 characters.

Comment: Yep I've seen those characters on the no-list.

Comment: Simple attack: find sticky notes under keyboards because no one can remember their password.

Comment: @Jeff, that is correct. If I leave my notebook at home, the passwords are too complicated to remember, so I'm unable to log in. And on the payroll system, I put the username and password as part of the bookmark.

Comment: "cannot contain any string (forwards or backwards) that is a word (3 or more letters long) in English" This was the one that got me. Dictionary attacks aren't effective if the password *contains* whole words, but rather if the whole password consists of nothing but full words... Well really one full word or very common phrases. The most secure passwords that are practical to use without writing down are passphrases that come from books, poems, song lyrics, etc -- change a few letters into numbers, misspell something, and capitalize unpredictably and no one is going to crack that password.

Comment: Character filtering is a sure sign of untested garbage code in the background. Developers need to learn to escape strings.

Comment: I would have added "less than eight characters" as a requirement to make it _really_ hard :-)

Answer (score 7):

Not all input devices (hardware-wise) often have all characters a full keyboard has, or likewise. If one is not using a password manager, one could find oneself in trouble entering such password, no?
And Unicode is still a far way (far far way) from being a standard.

Comment: Usually the people entering passwords will use the same hardware (or hardware class) for creating them and authenticating them.  I do not see how this is an argument in limiting character sets or length.  As for Unicode, when building the server-side (the authenticating part) why would you limit the size or character sets ?  any system requiring a password to enter should be able to control how this password is entered in the system, thus, if you require unicode for your client then so be it !

Comment: @Newtopian You're assuming you don't have to interface with legacy systems, or systems outside your control.

Comment: they asked for a *good* reason, this isn't a *good* reason

Comment: @Jarrod - Not being able to enter a password is not a good reason?! In any case, I didn't see you come up with a better one (or any at all).

Comment: @Newtopian - (your first assumption) Why do you assume that? For example, I cannot enter most of my passwords from my mobile phone because it doesn't have central european characters. And this is the most obvious example. Passwords should always be based on the 
common denumirator principle.

Comment: @Rook you should not have used those characters if you knew you could not pick them from a device, that doesn't make it a *good* reason to limit them for everyone, it makes it a *good* reason for you **personally** not to use them.

Comment: i too need sometimes to enter password from my mobile phone... and it too will allow me to enter Chinese characters if i want to, does not mean i will though but there is no reason i should not based solely on the fact that some dont have the same character sets.  Going on the lowest common denominator then you should reduce possibilities to using solely numerical characters as they are the only ones that are ubiquitous...  although...  i'm sure we can find some hardware without numbers...

Comment: @Jarrod - Uhmm, yes ... it kinda does! I have four of them in my first and last name, which form my username, which was chosen by the bank, and I have a cell phone which doesn't support them. Tell me, now that you know the situation, which part of that is my personal fault?!! Should I change maybe my name maybe? Or should I call the bank's IT center and tell them you'll be there first thing monday morning to fix the damn thing?

Comment: @Newtopian: Can you be certain that typing the characters on the phone will give a bit-identical representation?  Some Unicode characters have multiple representations, and it's possible that one browser might use one representation for a character and a different one might use a different representation.  If rules for composite characters change, a database containing unencrypted characters represented one way could be normalized to use a different representation, but encrypted passwords would be another matter.

Comment: @supercat: For identical representation, you convert either to canonically precomposed or to canonically decomposed. That's for example what Apple's filesystem on MacOS and iOS does; any Unicode character is allowed and handled just fine.

Answer (score 6):

One reason for limiting characters would be due to how the password is then input.

Several banks for example, with their Internet Banking websites, ask for specific characters from a password, and you select the appropriate characters via a drop-down box.

They do this, presumably, so that keyloggers cannot detect the keypress, and thus know [characters from] your password. While I know that there are many other ways such measures could be circumvented e.g. screencapture; it is still effective against keyloggers.

If they had to allow all characters, then the length of the dropdown box would become cumbersome, and also allow for confusion between similar looking characters.

Comment: Surely (technical) people would just key in the letter anyway?

Comment: @Gerry - that's a browser specific behaviour rather than an absolute standard and it's also dependent on user knowledge to make it workable.

Comment: My bank used a popup applet of a keyboard for a similar reason. But it was too difficult to use and got a lot of criticism for being inaccessible (didn't work for screen readers, alternate input etc)

Comment: @Jon - I did say technical people, and I don't know of any windows browsers that don't implement at least first character matching, as it is standard Windows behaviour - can't speak for Mac and *nix

Comment: @Gerry The browser on my Android phone doesn't allow this.  I expect it's the same for a lot of mobile devices.

Answer (score 2):

Disallowing special chars like tab would be valid. You can logon or change your password with a tab char in text mode but you can't use it in a GUI or web environment. A backslash char will also present some cross-platform issues.

btw long passwords are not passwords - they are passphrases. Your average user cannot remember 2Z8d!%g#x but they can remember 'the name of my pet is fido the dog'. Longer text is harder to crack via brute force and is far less likely to be written on a note attached to the screen.

Comment: See also https://xkcd.com/936/

Answer (score 0):

When people type they make mistakes, called "typos". Normally people see their mistakes and correct them. For password entry usually you can't see what you've typed and therefore you can't correct your typos. You make mistakes without realising it, submit your password, and it comes back as "password invalid". Then you try again. Then you try again.

You can think of it as "3 minor little typos and then you're indistinguishable from a brute force attack". How do systems defend against brute force attacks? An explicit "*Too many attempts, go away, you won't be able to log in even if you do get it right*" response? Exponentially increasing delays on password entry leading to browser time-outs when the delay is too long, making it impossible to try to log in again? Approaches vary, but there's always a consequence in a well designed system.

You can think of it as "3 minor little typos and then you get some kind of denial of service".

As password length increases the risk of typos (and therefore the risk of denying an authorised person's access) increases. Anything longer than about 20 characters is going to be mistyped frequently (unless the user is smart/lazy and stores their password somewhere so they can "copy and paste" without worrying about typos, like a nice plain text file on their desktop called "*passwords.txt*").

Answer (score -2):

It prevents the user from **reusing passwords.**

The user has a 20-character-long password with symbols like `*` and `#` (which are accessible on all keyboards, even phone call keyboards). But this user thinks this psasword is so safe, and nobody could have hacked it even if he gets pwned on some other website he uses the same password with (assuming the website uses a proper hashing algorithm).

Now he comes to this website that only allows `[A-Za-z0-9]{8,16}`. He can't use this password anymore. He is forced to choose another password. This ends the era of his 20-character-long star-hash-everywhere password. Now he is safe even if he uses the password on a site that does not hash the password.

Disclaimer: the user is me.

Comment: Being actively hostile towards the user barely makes for good security practice, in this case as well. Users will start appending numbers and letters instead of special characters and you will be left with the reduced entropy